# Get EHIC after I lived outside the EU my whole life

Tags: immigration, france, social-security, hungarian-citizens, ehic

My parents are European and they got me Hungarian citizenship. They migrated to a non-EU country several years before I was born. Since 3 months ago I'm living in France. I think that here paying social security is obligatory.

What's the procedure for getting my EHIC from France? I heard from somebody that I need to ask in Budapest for a questionnaire S1. Is it so? Can I do it via Internet and send it to my French address?

Comment: The healthcare schemes I'm aware of cover people according to their residence. If Hungary's is like most other systems, you're not eligible unless you live there.  Instead, you should seek coverage under the French system as a resident of France.

Comment: @phoog I visited my CPAM center and they told me also to bring an S1 form from social security in Budapest... They told me that as long as I don't come with a visa from my non-EU country I can only be covered by my Hungarian nationality.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @phoog CAF required that in order to get reimbursements for my rent I'd be enrolled in CPAM/mutelle and have EHIC. I might begin studying here in a year or so but until then I need to pay my rent.

Comment: You may not be eligible for rent subsidies.  Furthermore, under [Directive 2004/38/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616), France is only required to let you stay for longer than three months if you either have a job or "have sufficient resources for [yourself] not to become a burden on the social assistance system of [France] during [your] period of residence and have comprehensive sickness insurance cover in [France]."  But I don't know much about France's transposition of this requirement.

Comment: @phoog Yes.. I'm in a "pre-doctoral"  internship. It means I'm working on something towards phd but I'm not enrolled "ex-officio" so I can't enjoy LMDE and other muttelles.